# Neighbours and New Year Party

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I was able to get through the sample test case but my solution failed after submission. **Can anyone tell me where i am going wrong??**

**Question:**

In the XYZ society, the neighbours hate each other for their attitude. Various activities are organized in the society for Welcoming the New Year. The tickets were provided to each house with an integer written on it. Some got tickets with positive integers and some got tickets with negative integers. In the evening, people had to carry their tickets to the club house where the eligible ones will get the exciting gifts. The eligibility of winning the gift depends on the maximum sum which can be formed from the tickets numbers keeping in mind that neighbours hate each other. Since the neighbours hate each other, the two cannot be together in the list of maximum sum.

The President of the society, Mr. Singh, is a wise man and know that neighbours in society don’t like each other. Also, he don’t wish to become bad in front of people. So, he came up with an idea to design a program which will provide the list of integers forming maximum sum and thus all the members of the list will be given the gifts. The only problem with this idea is that he don’t know programming so he is asking you to provide the correct list of integers. The people may be annoying but are smart and will fight if the list provided by you doesn’t form the maximum sum.

> **Note**: The integer written on ticket of individuals may or may not be
>   unique. In case, when there are two list with equal maximum sum, the
>   list with first greater element would be considered. For better
>   understanding, look at the explanation of Test case 4 in Sample Test
>   Case. The tickets with integer 0 are not considered for winning the
>   gifts.

Input Format
The first line of input consist of number of test cases, T.

The first line of each test case consist of the number of houses (tickets distributed) in society, N.

The second line of each test case consist of N space separated tickets with integer written on them.

Constraints

- 1<= T <=10
- 1<= N <=10000
- -1000<= Integer_on_Ticket <=1000

> Output Format For each test case, print the ticket numbers in a single
>   line forming the maximum sum in the format similar to Sample Test
>   Case.

Sample TestCase 1

> Input

5

5

-1 7 8 -5 4

4

3 2 1 -1

4

11 12 -2 -1

4

4 5 4 3

4

5 10 4 -1

**Output**

48

13

12

44

10

**My Solution:**

```
x=int(input(''))
for i in range(0,x):
    y=int(input(''))        
    s=input('')
    houses=s.split()
    houses1=[int(item) for item in houses]
    Nhouses=[]
    even=[]
    odd=[]
    final=[]
    final1=[]
    for p in range(0,len(houses1)):
        if p%2==0:
            even.append(houses1[p])
        else:
            odd.append(houses1[p])

    for i in houses1:
        if i<0:
            Nhouses.append(i)

    if houses1==Nhouses:
        maxi=max(Nhouses)
        print(maxi)
    else:
        sum_even=0
        sum_odd=0

        for i in even:
            if i>0:
                sum_even+=i
                final.append(i)

        for i in odd:
            if i>0:
                sum_odd+=i
                final1.append(i)

        final.reverse()
        final1.reverse()
        final2=[]
        if sum_even>sum_odd:
            for j in final:
                print(j,end="")
        elif sum_odd>sum_even:
            for j in final1:
                print(j,end="")
        else:
            for i,j in zip(final,final1):
                if i>j:
                    final2=final
                    break
                else:
                    final2=final1
            for j in final2:
                print(j,end="")
        print()
```

Comment: a more specific question would be better than just copy pasting the whole task

Comment: Hint: The maximum sum that can be achieved by looking at the first i tickets only, and including ticket i, is equal to x[i] plus the maximum sum that can be achieved by looking at the first i-1 tickets only, and *not* including ticket i-1.  Look for a way to also compute that second quantity efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard DP problem based on Kadane's algorithm.

Consider this -

```
// Constant space DP-solution to calculate maximum sum in the given
// array with no adjacent elements considered
int maxSumSubseq(int arr[], int n)
{
    // base case
    if (n == 1)
        return arr[0];

    // store maximum sum till index i-2
    int prev_prev = arr[0];

    // stores maximum sum till index i-1
    int prev = max(arr[0], arr[1]);

    // start from index 2
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
    {
        // curr stores the maximum sum till index i
        int curr = max(arr[i], max(prev, prev_prev + arr[i]));
        prev_prev = prev;
        prev = curr;

    }
    // return maximum sum
    return prev;
}
```

Moreover, I would suggest you to wait for the competition to get over and then you will get answers automatically.

Comment: how do you consider to capture the elements that constitute the max sum?

Comment: You can create two string variables which will go hand to hand and update when sum is updated.

Comment: The above solution is actually not helpful when it comes to track element. I would suggest you to edit the answer according to what actually asked.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the maximum sum from the array:

```
public static int getMaximumValue(int[] neighbour) {

        int incl = neighbour[0];
        int excl = 0; 
        int excl_new; 

        for (int i = 1; i < neighbour.length; i++) {
            excl_new = (incl > excl) ? incl : excl;
            incl = excl + neighbour[i];
            excl = excl_new;
        }
       return ((incl > excl) ? incl : excl);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```
def get_pair(t, N):
    if len(t) == 0:
        return

    s = None
    cor = []

    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            if i == j or abs(i - j) == 1 or t[i] == 0 or t[j] == 0:
                continue
            if s == None or t[i] + t[j] > s:
                s = t[i] + t[j]
                cor.append(t[i])
                cor.append(t[j])

    for i in t:
        if i > s:
            return [i]

    return cor




def main():
    T = int(input())
    while T>0:
        N = int(input())
        t = input()
        t = t.split()
        t = [int(i) for i in t]

        l = get_pair(t, N)
        if len(l) == 1:
        print(l[0])
        else:
            s = str(l[-1])+str(l[-2])
            print(s)

    T = T - 1

main()
```

Comment: Did this clear all test cases without timeout? This seems like a O(N^2) solution.

Answer (score 0):

/* Program follow binary search algorithm */

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <stdbool.h>
#include    <string.h>
// function to return sum of elements 
// in an array of size n 
int sum(int arr[], int n) 
{ 
    int sum = 0; // initialize sum 

    // Iterate through all elements  
    // and add them to sum 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    sum += arr[i]; 

    return sum; 
} 



bool inc_byte_binary(unsigned int *binaryStream,int n)                  // Binary increment in byte
{
    unsigned int carry = 1;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        binaryStream[i] = binaryStream[i]^carry ;
        carry = binaryStream[i]&carry   ;
        //printf("%d ",binaryStream[i]);

    }
    if(sum((int*)binaryStream,n)==0)
        return false;
    else
        return true;

}




 bool isNeighbourMatch(unsigned int *binaryStream,int b_n)          // match binary in neighbour
 {
     int n = b_n*sizeof(int)*8;
     int p_i= n;
     int i;
     for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(binaryStream[i]==1)
            {
                if(i == p_i+1)
                    break;
                else
                    p_i=i;
            }

        }
        if(i<n)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
 }
 bool get_nextnn_bin(unsigned int *binaryStream,int b_n)        //next binary with neighbour not match
 {
    int i;
   // return false;
     do
     {
        if(inc_byte_binary(binaryStream,b_n)==false)
            break;

     }while( isNeighbourMatch(binaryStream, b_n));

     if(sum((int*)binaryStream,b_n)>0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
 }
 int sum_by_bin(int *ticket,unsigned int *binaryStream,int n){      // sum of one in the binary of ticket


     int sum=0;
     for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(binaryStream[i]==1)
            {
                    sum+=ticket[i];

            }

        }
        return sum;

 }
bool validate_zero_in_stream(int *ticket,unsigned int *binaryStream,int n)  // Validate good sequency, if it not have zero
{
   //int n = b_n*sizeof(int);
    int i;
     for( i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(binaryStream[i]==1)
            {
                if(ticket[i]==0)
                    break;
            }

        }
        if(i<n)
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
}
 int next_positive(unsigned int *binaryStream, int r_bin)         // move downgrade
{
    do
    {
    r_bin--;
    } while(r_bin>=0 && binaryStream[r_bin]==0);
    return r_bin;
}
void print_bin(unsigned int *binaryStream,int n)    // print the binar seq
{
    //int n = b_n*sizeof(int);

    for(int i=n;i>0;i--)
    {

        printf("%d",binaryStream[i-1]);
    }
}
void print_ticket(int *ticket,unsigned int *binaryStream,int n) // print the ticket based on binary seq
{
    //int n = b_n*sizeof(int);

    for(int i=n;i>0;i--)
    {
       if(binaryStream[i-1]==1)
       { 
        //printf("%d",binaryStream[i-1]);
        printf("%d",ticket[i-1]);
       }
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *a[])
{
    int t,n,p_n,r_n;

    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%d",&n);
    int *ticket = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%d",&ticket[i]);

    unsigned int *binaryStream = (unsigned int*)calloc(sizeof(int),n);
    unsigned int *r_binaryStream = (unsigned int*)calloc(sizeof(int),n);

// Apply binary search algorithm
    while(get_nextnn_bin(binaryStream,n)==true)
    {


       if(validate_zero_in_stream(ticket,binaryStream,n) == false)
        {

            if(sum_by_bin(ticket,binaryStream,n) > sum_by_bin(ticket,r_binaryStream,n))

               memcpy(r_binaryStream,binaryStream,n*sizeof(int)) ;

            else if(sum_by_bin(ticket,binaryStream,n) == sum_by_bin(ticket,r_binaryStream,n))
            {

                int r_i =n,c_i=n;
                while(r_i>=0 && c_i>0)
                {
                    r_i = next_positive(r_binaryStream,r_i);
                    c_i = next_positive(binaryStream,c_i);
                    if(r_i>=0 && c_i>=0)
                    {
                        if(ticket[c_i]>ticket[r_i])
                        {
                            memcpy(r_binaryStream,binaryStream,n*sizeof(int));
                            break;
                        }
                    }else
                        break;

                }
            }
        }  


    }
    print_ticket(ticket,r_binaryStream,n); 

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Max sum with no adjacent element is a standard problem in DP but the more interesting thing which was asked was the **reverse order** of tracked elements in the list which consitute the max sum.

Tracking element is what we need to do. The below algorithm is **O(N)** implementation.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

private static String getReverse(ArrayList<Integer> maxList) {
    String reverse = "";
    for (Integer i : maxList) {
        if (i != 0) {
            reverse = i + reverse;
        }
    }
    return reverse;
}

private static String findTicketOrderForMaxSum(int[] tickets) {
    int excludingNeighbours = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> excludingMaxSumList = new ArrayList<>();

    int includingNeighbours = tickets[0];
    ArrayList<Integer> maxSumIndicesList = new ArrayList<>();
    maxSumIndicesList.add(0);

    for (int i = 1; i < tickets.length; i++) {
        final int currentBestIncludingNeighbours;
        final ArrayList<Integer> currentBestSumList;
        if (excludingNeighbours > 0) {
            currentBestIncludingNeighbours = excludingNeighbours + tickets[i];
            currentBestSumList = new ArrayList<>(excludingMaxSumList);
        } else {
            currentBestIncludingNeighbours = tickets[i];
            currentBestSumList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        currentBestSumList.add(i);

        excludingNeighbours = includingNeighbours;
        excludingMaxSumList = new ArrayList<>(maxSumIndicesList);

        if (currentBestIncludingNeighbours > includingNeighbours) {
            includingNeighbours = currentBestIncludingNeighbours;
            maxSumIndicesList = currentBestSumList;
        }
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> elements = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Integer i: maxSumIndicesList){
        elements.add(tickets[i]);
    }
    return getReverse(elements);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int testCases = in.nextInt();
    while (testCases > 0) {
        int houseTickets = in.nextInt();
        int[] tickets = new int[houseTickets];

        for (int i = 0; i < houseTickets; i++) {
            tickets[i] = in.nextInt();
        }

        String ticketOrder = findTicketOrderForMaxSum(tickets);
        System.out.println(ticketOrder);

        testCases--;
    }
}
}
```

I would say the solution to get sum is slight modification of **Kadane's algorithm** along with tracking the best sum we can achieve by excluding/including the elements at a given index while iteration.